# Gödel's second incompleteness theorem

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

Apparently, see Feferman or Wikipedia, in a consistent system there are formulations of consistency that are demonstrable in the system itself while others are not. What distinguishes one from another? For example, isn't Gödel's second incompleteness theorem valid for any formulation of consistency  of P? If not, why is his proof valid for his formulation of consistency and not for others?

Comment: The second incompleteness theorem holds (among others) for provability predicates satisfying the Hilbert–Bernays–Löb derivability conditions. You can find that on Wikipedia. This isn’t really a question suitable for this site; it might be more appropriate at https://math.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I think that this question would not necessarily have much luck getting a good answer on MSE, so really is fine here. One of my criteria is whether, concerning things that I've had some interest in over the years, I can or cannot immediately see/know "the answer". Here, I could not, so I respect this as a reasonable question. :)

Comment: I also think that MSE would be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: As I already mentioned, the needed derivability conditions are explained in the Wikipedia article on Gödel's incompleteness theorems (and they have a more detailed dedicated article of their own). That, for me, is a clear indication that the question is not research-level. Furthermore, the OP should already know this, considering that he refered to the Wikipedia article in the question itself, so he just needs to read more carefully.

Comment: The problem is then to construct a provability predicate that satisfies the Hilbert–Bernays provability conditions, that might not even exist.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked and answered before on this site; e.g., [Clarification of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28025), [Is there a consistent arithmetically definable extension of PA that proves its own consistency?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231007), [In what sense does the sentence con(PA) "say" that PA is consistent?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/458983) See also [Relationship between first and second incompleteness theorems](https://mathoverflow.net/q/232209).

Comment: To answer the question in a nutshell, one can write down provability predicates Prv($\varphi$) that are *extensionally* correct but *intensionally* incorrect; i.e., they don't correctly *express* or *say* that "$\varphi$ is provable," even though Prv($\varphi$) happens to be true if and only if $\varphi$ is provable. Gödel's second incompleteness theorem does not apply to these intensionally incorrect predicates.

Comment: @Timothy Chow That's like saying that Gödel's second incompleteness theorem is true because it only applies to those consistency formulations for which Gödel's second incompleteness theorem is true.

Comment: @Speltzu If you actually want to learn something about this subject, you should look up what "extensional" and "intensional" mean, rather than try to pick a fight in the comments while speaking out of ignorance.

Comment: It seems like as if we know that Gödel's second incompleteness theorem is false but we refuse to admit it, and so we construct tailor-made consistency formulations so that it is not.